# automatically display "please enter text here" in specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, double-click

Simply I want to use the double click to clear content feature on vba.

I have a cell (B5) to be specific that needs to display "please enter text here" whenever there is no text in that cell and once the user double clicks the cell, it will erase and allow users to enter their desired text. If the users leave it and it's empty like i said it should display "please enter text here..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never done it before so apologies if this is wrong but this seems to work.
Place the below in the worksheets code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Cells(5, 2)) Is Nothing Then Target.Clear
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Cells(5,2).Value = "" Then Cells(5,2).Value = "Please enter text."
End Sub
```

Comment: This is good! it works however I'm protecting my worksheet so no one else can edit or change my other cells. For that specific b5 cell when i double click, it looks like it changes the format of that cell from being unlocked to locked. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Change the .Clear to .Value = ""

Comment: Mate you are a legend

Comment: Protect the worksheet with the [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) using `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`.

Comment: I don't understand how this works or what you think **Target** is. In the [Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.beforedoubleclick.aspx) event macro, Target is the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) so why aren't you using it? Further, why are leaving the *edit on double-click* active? It should be **Cancel:=True**.

Comment: Further, in the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro you are reassigning **Target**. Why on earth would you reassign Target? More, how does this not call itself into a reiterative loop when you change the values in a worksheet without suspending events with `Application.EnableEvents = False`?

Comment: Above me, I am sure you can throw together a better answer.

Comment: I accept you are better at it than me. I am reading and trying to fix it a little. I appreciate the chance to fix it and the feedback. I wasn't meaning to be nasty at all.

Answer (score 0):

You stated *'...and allow users to enter their desired text.'* I am going to assume a **General** cell format for the user-typed text.

In the worksheet's code sheet:

```
Option Explicit

'you can only double click a single cell so
'no worries about Target being more than one cell here
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Cells(5, "B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        'Cancel = True    'only if you want to disable 'in-cell' editing
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        With Target
            If .Value2 = "please enter text here..." Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Clear
            End If
        End With
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'there is a worry about Target being more than one cell here
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Cells(5, "B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim tmp As Variant
        With Cells(5, "B")
            If Not CBool(Len(.Value2)) Then
                .Font.ColorIndex = 10
                .Font.Italic = True
                .Value = "please enter text here..."
                .NumberFormat = "<@>"
            Else
                tmp = .Value
                .Clear
                .Value = tmp
            End If
        End With
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'special cases when B5 is double-clicked but no input provided
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Cells(5, "B")
        If Not CBool(Len(.Value2)) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Font.ColorIndex = 10
            .Font.Italic = True
            .Value = "please enter text here..."
            .NumberFormat = "<@>"
        End If
    End With
bm_Safe_Exit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This seems to cover everything¹ I threw at it while minimizing computation time and effort. It provides rudimentary error control to maintain a stable user environment.

---

¹ <sub>Please do not ask me to explain anything without doing your own research first. If you find a specific point that you are having trouble with, I will endeavour to assist; if you cannot grasp a concept then take a course, it is beyond the scope of this venue to explain it all.</sub>